# Inserting data using prepared statement fails with a warning "Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement"

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm unable to insert data entry. I spent several hours, looking at various tutorials and sample code, but I can't figure out why the following does not work:

```
$data1 = 0;
$data2 = "pumpkin";
$data3 = "cake";
$data4 = "orange";
$data5 = "sweet";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
// Here I have a few SELECT queries that checks if $data2 and/or $data3 is already taken
$query = "INSERT INTO ". $mytable . " SET data1=?, data2=?, data3=?, data4=?, data5=?";
if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("issss", $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5);
    $stmt->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error); // added per Your Common Sense's suggestion
    //$stmt->bind_result($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5);
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error; // edited per Yogesh Suthar's suggestion
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

I get an error on `$stmt->bind_result` line.

> *Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement*

What am I doing wrong?

I have the following on top with $db_user, $db_password, $db_dbname properly defined:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_dbname);
```

Comment: There is no result on insert statements.

Comment: @datasage, I have removed the bind_result line, but I am still unable to insert a new row of data to the table.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query format is wrong, you seem to be combining and update query with an insert query. `Insert into table (col1,col2,...) Values (?,?,...)`

Comment: @datasage This query is perfect. We can use in this way also.

Comment: is this table for educational puropse? Nor column names nor inserted data looks suitable for the one row but more like for the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line, because you are firing `INSERT` query and it returns number of rows affected. You have to use `bind_result` only for `SELECT` query.

```
$stmt->bind_result($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5);
```

use this

```
echo $mysqli->error;
```

instead of

```
echo "failed";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I commented out the bind_result line, and it no longer gives me error warning.  However, the insert isn't happening, and no new data entry is made to the database.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Naomi Can you explain what this line do `$mysqli->stmt_init()`?

Comment: I don't actually know what $mysqli->stmt_init() does. I was looking at the following tutorial to get me started on converting procedural php statements to prepared statements, and I thought it would just do its job. [Tutorial 1](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/)

Comment: @Naomi your code is perfect.:) but i don't know why it is not working. You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658722/prepared-statement-not-letting-me-call-mysqli-stmt-init

Comment: BTW, SELECT statement is working for me (at least with a couple of SELECT queries I needed to perform.) And I have the same $mysqli->stmt_init() in these php files.  I'm not sure if it means anything... Also, if you have any suggestions for a comprehensive tutorial available somewhere online, I'd like to hear about it.  To me, it's such a struggle, trying to figure out how to do the prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you, @Yogesh Suther.  I will take a look at the link you've posted.  If you have any other suggestion, please post more.  It feels like I need lots of help until I can start running again.

Comment: @Naomi If your `SELECT` is working then try this query for `INSERT`. `INSERT INTO your_table_name(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5) values(?,?,?,?,?)`. I am sure this query will work. And about tutorial link `PHP's` online manual is perfect for it.

Comment: Suther, I've tried it too, but it didn't work for me.  I was at my wits end when I decided to seek help by posting here.

Comment: So what happened is, with your error code and Your Common Sense's error code, I was able to learn that I did not supply key data.  I'll explain up top.  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

if data is not inserted then there was an error.
So you have to ask mysql for this error

```
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```

so, you will be notified of the certain error and there will be no need for guesswork.